# Marlowe: Value -> Integer

Tags: marlowe

How to change the type of Value to Integer?
Or pass Value type as parameter to Bouds (*between (parameter1 :: Value) and  (parameter1 :: Value)*)?

Comment: Could you please describe what are you trying to do?
There is a evalValue function in Semantics.hs which evaluates a Value expression to Integer.

Comment: In brief: choiceId name party = ChoiceId name party, next step: payment name party  = ChoiceValue (choiceId name party)... and value payment I want to convert to Integer...
Thanks for the hint. How easy is it to use this function in this case?